# How to force delete COALESCE function in query. C# EntityFramework 7.0.2 LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, coalesce

Ok, I have such SQL code:

```sql
DECLARE  @documentId INT = 8
SELECT 
    i.[status]      AS [status],
    i.[barcode]     AS [barcode],
    i.[containerId] AS [containerTypeId],
    (
        SUM(ISNULL(lp.[Weight], 0) * il.[factCount]) + 
        ISNULL(lpt.[Weight], 0)
    )               AS [weight],
    i.[comment]     AS [comment]
FROM [Items]                   AS i    WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ItemsLines]   AS il   WITH(NOLOCK) ON i.[id]          = il.[itemsId] 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LagerOptions] AS lp   WITH(NOLOCK) ON lp.[lagerId]    = il.[lagerId]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LagerOptions] AS lpt  WITH(NOLOCK) ON lpt.[lagerId]   = i.[containerId]
WHERE @documentId = i.[documentId] 
GROUP BY i.[status], i.[barcode], i.[containerId], i.[comment], lpt.[Weight]
```

The most similar code I've written in LINQ is:

```cs
var lots = await (

    from i in _dbContext.Items
    join lpt in _dbContext.LagerOptions on i.ContainerId equals lpt.LagerId into lptTable 
    from lpt in lptTable.DefaultIfEmpty()

    // The sum of all lagers for current lot
    let lotWeight = (
        from il in _dbContext.ItemsLines
        join lp in _dbContext.LagerOptions on il.LagerId equals lp.LagerId into lpTable 
        from lp in lpTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where il.ItemsId == i.Id
        select (il.FactCount * lp.Weight.GetValueOrDefault(0))
    ).Sum()

    where i.DocumentsId == documentId
    select new
    {
        Status = i.Status,
        Barcode = i.Barcode,
        ContainerTypeId = i.ContainerId,
        // total weight with container Weight
        Weight = lotWeight + lpt.Weight.GetValueOrDefault(0),
        //
        Comment = i.Comment
    }
).ToListAsync();
```

For SQL query the results can contain empty lots or lots with null-weight lagers (problem lagers) that makes "Weight" field of lot is equal NULL that helps detect problem lots.

But when I check the C# LINQ code EntityFramework create a COALESCE() function over SUM() function
and the query converted to SQL looks like this:

```sql
SELECT [t].[status] AS [Status], [t].[barcode] AS [Barcode], [t].[containerId] AS [ContainerTypeId], (
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM([t0].[factCount] * COALESCE([l0].[Brutto], 0.0)), 0.0)
    FROM [dbo].[ItemsLines] AS [t0]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LagerOptions] AS [l0] ON [t0].[lagerId] = [l0].[lagerId]
    WHERE [t0].[itemsId] = [t].[id]) + COALESCE([l].[weight], 0.0) AS [Weight], [t].[comment] AS [Comment]
FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LagerOptions] AS [l] ON [t].[containerId] = [l].[lagerId]
WHERE [t].[documentId] = @__documentId_0
```

As a result, the weight of the problem lot will be equal to the container weight of this lot.
I can solve the problem with crutch methods, but I'm sure that there is a simple solution, which, unfortunately, I did not find.

I tryed to add different checks on null and rewrite the query for different JOIN patterns, but the main problem - EntityFramework create a COALESCE() function over SUM() function. And I don't know how to fix it in root. I work with C# EF approximately 1 month. EF 7.0.2

Help me, please.

!!EDITED

Correct LINQ query looks like this (Thank, [Svyatoslav Danyliv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10646316/svyatoslav-danyliv)):

```
var query = 
    from i in _dbContext.Items
    join il in _dbContext.ItemsLines on i.Id equals il.ItemsId into ilj
    from il in ilj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join lp in _dbContext.LagerOptions on il.LagerId equals lp.LagerId into lpj
    from lp in lpj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join lpt in _dbContext.LagerOptions on i.ContainerId equals lpt.LagerId into lptj
    from lpt in lptj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where i.DocumentsId == documentId
    group new { lp, il, lpt } by new { i.Status, i.Barcode, i.ContainerId, i.Comment, lpt.Weight } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.Status,
        g.Key.Barcode,
        ContainerTypeId = g.Key.ContainerId,
        Weight = g.Sum(x => ((decimal?)x.lp.Weight) ?? 0 * x.il.FactCount) + g.Key.Weight ?? 0
        g.Key.Comment,
    };
```

But the query converted to SQL looks like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    [t].[status] AS [Status], 
    [t].[barcode] AS [Barcode], 
    [t].[containerId] AS [ContainerTypeId], 
    COALESCE(SUM(COALESCE([l].[weight], 0.0) * [t0].[factCount])), 0.0) + 
    COALESCE([l0].[weight], 0.0) AS [Weight], 
    [t].[comment] AS [Comment]
FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ItemsLines] AS [t0] ON [t].[id] = [t0].[itemsId]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LagerOptions] AS [l] ON [t0].[lagerId] = [l].[lagerId]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LagerOptions] AS [l0] ON [t].[containerId] = [l0].[lagerId]
WHERE [t].[documentsId] = @__documentId_0
GROUP BY [t].[status], [t].[barcode], [t].[containerId], [t].[comment], [l0].[weight]
```

EntityFramework create a COALESCE() function over SUM() function.
How to remove this?

Comment: LINQ isn't SQL or embedded SQL and that SQL code shows huge problems. `NOLOCK` doesn't mean `take no locks` it means `read dirty, duplicate or random data while taking table-level locks and throwing from time to time`.

Comment: LINQ by itself doesn't query databases. It's a query language for ORMs like Entity Framework. You don't write JOINs in it. It's the job of the ORM to generate any JOINS needed from the relations between *entities* - not tables.

Comment: The LINQ query isn't equivalent to the SQL query either. The SQL query has a `SUM(ISNULL(lp.[Weight], 0) * il.[factCount])` on the original grouping while the LINQ query has an entire subquery in `let lotWeight`. That's equivalent to writing `SUM(SELECT .... WHERE il.ItemsId == i.Id)`.

Comment: My goal is not to completely convert sql to linq. I want to have results like using sql but using linq. About NOLOCK I know.
What the better way I can have in my situation? Maybe for this part the better way - using SQL procedure and call it using ef?

Comment: Use proper entities with proper relations. That will eliminate all hand-written JOINs. In the posted answer that would eliminate over half of the lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should equivalent LINQ query to your SQL. I do not understand why instead of grouping you have forced LINQ Translator to generate another query.

```cs
var query = 
    from i in _dbContext.Items
    join il in _dbContext.ItemsLines on i.Id equals il.ItemsId into ilj
    from il in ilj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join lp in _dbContext.LagerOptions on il.LagerId equals lp.LagerId into lpj
    from lp in lpj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join lpt in _dbContext.LagerOptions on i.ContainerId equals lpt.LagerId into lptj
    from lpt in lptj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where i.DocumentsId == documentId
    group new { lp, il, lpt } by new { i.Status, i.Barcode, i.ContainerId, i.Comment, lpt.Weight } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.Status,
        g.Key.Barcode,
        ContainerTypeId = g.Key.ContainerId,
        Weight = g.Sum(x => ((double?)x.lp.Weight) ?? 0 * x.il.FactCount) + g.Key.Weight ?? 0
        g.Key.Comment,
    };
```

Comment: "Another query", because I studying. I work with linq the small time. Your answer helps me to construct right query, thank you, but it not solve my problem fully. I write description in question body

Comment: Try to correct `(int?)x.il.FactCount ?? 0`. Probably EF Core detects that SUM can be nullable.

Comment: But the result of SUM can be and need to be NULL! The result of SUM needs to be a NULL (if problem lots are contain) or a decimal value...

Comment: The FactCount value is decimal. because it can be weight.

Comment: It is by [default](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/7ba08647b35431474712c1ecb9bb872e5c30da2c) LOL